# Simulating 3 phase mosfet bridge with LEDs

Tags: led, mosfet, analog, h-bridge, brushless-dc-motor

I have a commercial 3 phase BLDC motor driver board ([TI DRV8323 BoostXL](http://www.ti.com/tool/BOOSTXL-DRV8323RH)) and I want to write a firmware from scratch. For testing, I want to make sure I open/close the mosfets in correct order. I am thinking to use 3 LEDs to simulate motor windings but I am confused as the motor windings are in star arrangement... typically something like the image below:

[image]

Is there a way to simply attach LEDs to the outputs of the bridge and simulate this?

Another problem is that the supply voltage will be 24 volts but I want to use normal LED which I believe can be damaged above 5 volts...how to take care of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you merely want a visual indicator for port active, then use the Gate drive with series R & LED.

When you need to verify critical timing, such as deadtime > L/R & RC decay times and prevent shoot-thru, start with dummy load like a light bulb then introduce inductance while monitoring your thermal design with sensors.

I suggest you must include current sensors for feedback on faults.  Consider all aspects of critical unknown and how you will verify it and plan for DFT test design before you make it.

A tungsten light bulb will somewhat simulate the up to 10x start surge of an efficient motor or capacitive load, but without the reactive phase shift.